# Automating Mobile App Accelerometer Data Testing

Tags: automated-tests, adb, accelerometer, simulate

I am trying to create a test automation for my mobile app and I need to be able to simulate various accelerometer readings which would happen while the user is using the app.

I originally thought using ADB with and android emulator would work. However the command that is documented to work does not.

```
$ ./adb shell sensor set acceleration 1:1:1
/system/bin/sh: sensor: inaccessible or not found
```

Is there a specific software version or emulator or hardware which i need to use to enable the above command?

Can I do similar type tests with an iphone?

Answer (score 3):

you are using the wrong command, sensor set accelerometer is an emulator console command for which you have to use `./adb emu sensor set acceleration 1:1:1` command.

This will help you understand, https://helpmanual.io/help/adb/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).